# MAC address rewriting using tc

Tags: networking, iptables, ethernet, tc, netfilter

I am using `tc` to change the MAC address of incoming packets on a TAP interface (`tap0`) as follows where `mac_org` is the MAC address of a guest in a QEMU virtual machine and `mac_new` is a different MAC address that `mac_org` should be replaced with.

```
tc qdisc add dev tap0 ingress handle ffff:
tc filter add dev tap0 protocol ip parent ffff: \
  flower src_mac ${mac_org} \
  action pedit ex munge eth src set ${mac_new} pipe \
  action csum ip pipe \
  action xt -j LOG
```

I also add an iptables rule to log UDP packets on the input hook.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j LOG
```

syslog shows that indeed the DHCP discover packet is changed accordingly. The `tc` log entry looks as follows:

```
IN=tap0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:${mac_new}:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=338 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=318
```

and the log entry of the netfilter input hook which follows the `tc` ingress hook as the locally incoming packet is passed towards the socket shows the same result slightly differently formatted.

```
IN=tap0 OUT= MACSRC=${mac_new} MACDST=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff MACPROTO=0800 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=338 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=318
```

Before starting QEMU I run `dnsmasq` on `tap0` which surprisingly shows the output:

```
DHCPDISCOVER(tap0) ${mac_org}
```

Running `strace -f -x -s 10000 -e trace=network dnsmasq ...` shows a `recvmsg` call that contains `${mac_org}` instead of `${mac_new}`.

```
recvmsg(4, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(68), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, msg_namelen=16, msg_iov=[{iov_base="... ${mac_org} ..." ...
```

How can that happen? It almost appears as if the packet is altered after the netfilter input hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are confusing the Ethernet address that you modify with `tc` (link layer only), with the inner `CHADDR` field (client's hardware address) that was embedded by the client inside the `DHCPDISCOVER` request (application layer which won't ever be altered by `tc`).

Comment: Great catch. That is indeed the problem.